# Turn on and off the Spring Data Elasticsearch for SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

- What I am trying to achieve:

Turn on and off the Spring Data Elasticsearch for a SpringBoot application.

- What did I try:

I am using this code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyElasticConfiguration extends ReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("some-endpoint:9200").build();
    }

}
```

and this dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

    ...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

- Actual result:

With the above, my SpringBoot application will try to connect to Elasticsearch on startup.

- Expected result:

I wish to disable such connection attempts on startup.

- Question:

I tried searching for a property like: `spring.data.elasticsearch.enabled=false`, but no luck finding something similar.

Is there a way to turn on/off spring data elasticsearch, via some kind of properties, or some kind of of annotation?

Answer (score 2):

[Disable Spring configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-disable-auto-config) in bootstrap application class should solve your issue:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { MyElasticConfiguration.class })
YourProjectApplication {/*...*/}
```

You can also use `@Profile` to set an profile or exclude profile on `MyElasticConfiguration class`.